# facebook application authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to make native facebook aplication in python. I have problem with extended permission, on facebook application page I typed some types of permission which I need but when I try to get acces token by:
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token`

i get auth dialog which tells that application receive only basic information, it looks like it doesn't regard to extended permissions that I mentioned in application page on facebook.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @donatello,did you got worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add extra permissions while creating the application.You can get more information from here,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

The other method is you can add comma seperated permissions with in the auth dialog url itself a s follows

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
&state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING
```

for more details

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/